# How are hashes evaluated by gcc's preprocessor?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

What is the purpose of this block in stdint.h (from newlib)?

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && \
  ( (__GNUC__ >= 4) || \
    ( (__GNUC__ >= 3) && defined(__GNUC_MINOR__) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 2) ) )
/* gcc > 3.2 implicitly defines the values we are interested */
#define __STDINT_EXP(x) __##x##__
```

This macro is used later in the header for integer comparison but I'm not sure how it is supposed to evaluate. For example:

```
#if __STDINT_EXP(LONG_MAX) > 0x7fffffff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`##` is the cpp (C Preprocessor) operator to concatenate tokens, ie.

```
#if __STDIN_EXP(LONG_MAX) > 0x7fffffff
```

evaluates to

```
#if __LONG_MAX__ > 0x7fffffff
```

in the first step.

Comment: Note to future readers: cpp is the c pre-processor, not to be confused with c++ sources ending in .cpp

Answer (score 2):

The `##` operator means "concatenate" to the C preprocessor, so that line is equivalent to:

```
#if __LONG_MAX__ > 0x7fffffff
```

If you really want to know what happens on a given machine, run it through the preprocessor and find out.

Comment: The expansion of `__STDINT_EXP(LONG_MAX)` won't show up in preprocessed source either way, though.

Comment: @mmutz: Well, it sort of will. It looks like `9223372036854775807L` on my machine. That is, if it's not in an `#if` block like it is there.

Answer (score 1):

In the preprocessor `##` concatenates two pieces of text into one larger token. This particular macro slaps underscores on each side of an identifier, so if you are using gcc 3.2 or later this:

```
#if __STDINT_EXP(LONG_MAX) > 0x7fffffff
```

Turns into this:

```
#if __LONG_MAX__ > 0x7fffffff
```